# Planetesimal Habitation Grav-Train?

Tags: space, space-colonization, space-constructs

### The Ring

Let's say, for the sake of argument, we have a small, sort-of-heavy moon, with little geological activity, orbiting a gas giant. Let's take Ganymede. It has around 0.12Gs of surface gravity. This is great for launching materials and rockets, but it's horrible for human physiology, and probably plays more hell with Keidran biology for that matter.

If we want permanent homes in space, we need a full earths gravity, or close to it. What I propose is a rotating station. (groundbreaking, right?) But instead of just building a big space ring, what if we built a ring around the equator of a moon.

**A train.**

But why do we have to build a normal train? Why not make one thats 20 meters wide? 40 meters? Why not 200 meters wide? **A massive, modular ring.**

### The Habitat

This home away from home would be a a massive, modular habitat that spans the entire equator, perpendicular to the axis of rotation of the moon it is built on. It would ride on electromagnetic suspension rails with high-temperature superconductors.

To board the station, a second, parallel service track would run next to the ring, with tram cars able to slow to a stop at stations around the moon, and then speed up to the same speed as the ring so people and cargo can board it.

But why stop with one? We could cover the surface with them, but let's start with 7 tracks. If we spun all of them up to the same speed, the ones closest to the poles would have less gravity and worse coriolis. This is actually a good thing as it allows cargo to be moved with less energy.

A happy side effect of this is that if the rings are spun opposite to the rotation of the planet, it will slow down, possibly stopping. This is great if you wanted to build docks on the poles, with ships not needing to equalize with the station spin, or dock directly to the rings themselves.

In a capitalist economy, the outer rings will be the cheapest, dirtiest, most industrial parts of the habitat, probably housing cargo and freight. The ring cars would be three stories tall, with a service level above and below, handling electricity, life support, agriculture, water purification and industrial systems.

The middle level could house a tram system that ran the entire circumference of the station, being also a null-G test ground, as the tram would slow almost to a stop relative to the planet.

And lastly, around the rings could be a carbon fiber mesh that could catch runaway equipment if anything where to go wrong.

### The Question

What are the flaws? How can it be made more realistic? How practical is this approach compared to a regular space station?

Comment: The 1 g requirement for human habitability is far from certain. 0 g means no up and down at all, that's a lot more alien than just 0.1g. The requirement gets even murkier if one considers genetic enhancement or cybernetics.

Comment: This is a cool idea but it's quite perverse. You've got a body large enough to have appreciable gravity, but rather than exploit that for free, you spend a huge amount of resources to create an _opposed_ artificial gravitational force that exists only on artificial structures built around the body. This is very much the hard way, and a capitalist society wouldn't permit so much capital or resources to be wasted. Rather, they would just make people tolerate the low natural gravity.

Comment: @Tom good point, but for one, Ganymede is only an example, these trains would actually be **easier** to build on smaller, less dense moons.

Comment: For a second, the trains would only be for habitation and the heath of the crews that have to work on industries not on the rings themselves, such as forges, refineries, farms and other stuffs... Unfortunately, capitalism cant really force evolution to make us better at coping with the adverse effects of very low gravities.

Comment: "Unfortunately, capitalism cant really force evolution to make us better at coping with adverse effects" Have you *seen* the pharmaceutical industry? Sure, it's a difficult problem to get to grips with, but so is cancer, or Alzheimer's, or vaccinations, and that hasn't stopped anyone.

Comment: @Cadence... well... *runs out of arguments* your point is valid, but so is the rule of cool! As long as its not stupidly unbelievable, I'll take it! :3

Answer (score 3):

### Flaws

[image: diagram]

Gravity pulls inward, centrifugal force flings outward.

To get a full gee the train will first have to cancel out Ganymede's 0.12 gees. That begs the question, "why even put it on Ganymede? Why not build it in empty space where there is no gravity to cancel out?"

If the train is moving at Mach 16+, what could possibly be the benefits of having it *on* Ganymede? So you get see the gloomy landscape blur by at hypersonic speeds out the window? Would people ... actually *want* that?
To do anything on the surface, you'd have to slow down from 5.5 km/s. No small feat. If the train is instead a space station in orbit, the delta-v tax to Ganymede would be much, *much* less, merely the orbital velocity of the space station (a couple km/s, tops). You could achieve 1 gee centrifugal force with a *much* smaller ring, less design complexity, orders of magnitude less materials. Then you have to worry about maintaining a 8,300+ km long track, checking for cracks/meteorite impacts/abrasion, powering it, etc. There are an ungodly number of failure modes and things that could go wrong which all end with **Everyone Dies**.

In my opinion, the track material is put to better use in an array of space elevators and to leave the habitation to rotating rings/cylinders in orbit, if it's truly impossible for humans to survive long-term in low-gee environments despite medical advancements, regular exercise, and possible genetic conditioning.

Comment: Your point about failure modes is a good one. If anything goes wrong with a conventional rotating space station, maybe people are thrown into the floor or walls, but if anything goes wrong here, you hit the surface of Ganymede at several thousand kps. That's a heck of a risk assessment.

Answer (score 3):

Kim Stanley Robinson proposed a similar thing in his Mars trilogy... a habitat on Phobos used a train to provide artificial gravity. That was slightly simpler than your train, by virtue of only providing Martian gravity (0.38 gees), travelling at under 200m/s, only being ~60km long and only having to overcome Phobos' feeble half-milligee gravity, etc.

> What are the flaws? How can it be made more realistic?

The largest one, perhaps obviously, is safety. Consider environmental safety. Building such a thing on the *surface* of an airless moon means you need radiation shielding, and quite a lot of it if you're expecting to shield against things like high-energy galactic cosmic rays. On Earth you're sitting underneath ten tonnes of atmosphere and a planet-sized magnetic field. On Ganymede, there's negligible protection from its atmosphere and feeble magnetic field and its proximity to Jupiter still provides a [somewhat hostile radiation environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_(moon)#Radiation_environment). Add to that the risk from meteorite impact, and you can see that the surface isn't a place you'd want to do this sort of construction.

Now, Ganymede is relatively low density, and its crust is expected to be both pretty thick and mostly made of ice. There's plenty of scope for building monstrous nuclear powered (presumably fusion, probably using deuterium mined from Ganymede) tunnelling machines to carve out deep subsurface spaces that are extremely well shielded from the hostile environment of the surface, and even well protected against all but the largest of impactors and those could presumably be tracked by astronomers and dealt with via various means.

This doesn't eliminate other safety hazards to do with the train hitting stuff, stuff falling off the train, etc, though if there's a roof over the tunnel you can at least avoid the issue of being able to shoot orbiting spacecraft using stuff thrown out of your much-faster-than-escape-velocity vehicle.

> How practical is this approach compared to a regular space station?

Given Ganymede's surface gravity of 0.146 gees, in order to generate an apparent Earthlike gravity inside you need a centrifugal force of 1.146 gees... this manifests as a linear habitat speed of ~5.44km/s. A habitat in microgravity doesn't have this issue, but even if it had the same radius as Ganymede (a fearsome engineering exercise) it would still have a linear speed at the rim of 5.08km/s. Any debris impacts have the potential to be catastrophic, so you'd need substantial armoring in either case.

Now, the strength of the centrifugal force is proportional to the square of the angular velocity and the strength of the coriolis force is merely proportional to the angular velocity. If you half the radius of rotation whilst keeping artificial gravity levels the same, your angular velocity (and hence the strength of coriolis effects) goes up by a factor of $\sqrt 2$ and your linear velocity at the rim goes down by the same factor (increasing fall and impact safety).

Project Rho, as always, has [some good material on the subject of coriolis effects](http://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/artificialgrav.php#id--Problems_with_Spin_Grav--Spin_RPM_Limit), including this nice diagram:

[image: A diagram of the "comfort zone" of habitats spun to provide artificial gravity, with gravity limits between .3 and 1g, and rotation limit at 2rpm, showing that large habitat radii are needed to minimize coriolis effects and maximise comfortable gravity. For 1g, a minimum radius of 75m is proposed to remain below the 2rpm threshold]

You can see that the "comfort zone" (as derived from a bunch of papers, but no actual in-space experience yet) extends down to quite small radii. You don't need something as big as Ganymede to stop people suffering from coriolis effects like nausea and dizzyness.

Of course, in a small habitat coriolis effects will be a lot stronger than your Ganymede-sized track. A useful blog post on [oikofuge.com](https://oikofuge.com/coriolis-effect-rotating-space-habitat/) gives a formula for the horizontal deflection of  $d$ an object dropped from radius $r$ to radius $R$ in a rotating reference frame: $$d = R\left [ \sqrt{\left ( \frac{R^2}{r^2} - 1 \right )} - \arccos \left ( \frac{r}{R} \right ) \right ]$$ which is conveniently unaffected by the actual rotation rate of the object. I won't derive it for you here, but it is correct and only needs pretty simple trigonometry to prove it to yourself. You can see that for a 2km radius station, an object dropped from 2m to the floor gets a ~6cm deflection to anti-spinwards whereas on your Ganymede train it would only get a deflection of ~1.6mm which is basically negligible for humans. How much you care about this is up to you. From the point of view of story-telling or game-playing flavor, coriolis forces can add all sorts of interesting effects, IMHO.

Anyway. It might actually make a lot more sense to build hollow rock- or ice-clad habitats from asteroids, moonlets or ring material, with sufficient exterior thickness to protect against impacts and radiation. It is hard to judge the relative complexity of the engineering projects, but at the point where you're considering making multiple 5+ km/s, 16000 km-long train tracks (the other kind of *rail gun*) it doesn't seem implausible that you could make a bunch of 1-2km radius space habitats of this kind, and they be not just simpler than your circum-ganymedean train but safer, too... the outside rim of a 2km radius habitat is only going at 140m/s, and so is somewhat less vulnerable to impacts, and things flung off will be slightly more easy to retrieve.

Speaking of which,

> And lastly, around the rings could be a carbon fiber mesh that could catch runaway equipment if anything where to go wrong.

You don't "*catch*", you "*attempt to minimize destructive effects of the impact and spallation*". You'll be needing [Whipple shields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipple_shield).

Comment: Wow... thank you! I'd say... for one, Ganymede was an offhand example, but now that you talk about it, it would make a lot of sense to tunnel in and build these massive train-rings kilometers under the ice. If you did that, these trains could actually be a lot bigger, and if dug deep enough, could give a marginal reduction to gravity you have to fight to break even. It would also reduce the radius of the track, making it smaller and thus easier to build. So yes! Subterranean Trans-Ganemydean Grav-trains it is! (just rolls off the tongue!)

Comment: AND! It frees up the surface for more of those domed farms. Or whatever else you want the surface for. Fan-friggin-tastic!

Comment: For reference, humanity would have access to a small (12~ exawatt max) dyson sphere, described in my other post. Enough power at their disposal to be truly terrifying and awe striking, but not so far that they seem 'foreign' or 'alien'

Answer (score 2):

At such a large radius the trains need to move *extremely* fast to simulate earth gravity. If my calculations are correct 19366km/h. That's a *bit* faster than current trains and probably not feasible due to engineering issues.

For down-scaling: reducing the radius by a factor of 100 reduces the speed by a factor of 10. For example, with a radius of 263m (instead of Ganymede's 2.634.000m) the speed drops to 193km/h. That would be fine even with current day technology.

Meanwhile reducing apparent gravity has little effect; at Ganymede's radius 0.1g would still require 8583km/h. Still too fast to be trivial and the resulting acceleration would be less then simply using Ganymede's gravity.

For a strictly realistic approach, building such trains on celestial bodies with radii around 3000m or less would be the way to go. Then again, if you want those trains around Ganymede you can simply declare that for your story having a speed of (whatever fits your story best) is sufficient. Being able to ignore a factor of 1000 or more here and there is the main reason we have any kind of science fiction after all, which is a good thing, too.

(I used formulas from [here](https://blog.maxaller.name/gamedev/2017/02/19/gravity-on-circular-space-station.html).)

Comment: Well... If you were to build a space habitat just as big, you would still need those kinds of speeds.

Comment: Well for one, no atmosphere for drag per se. Secondly, the only real concern is structural stress, as the hanging track and trains themselves would need to deal with the centrifugal force of creating a full gravity.

Comment: And once its moving, it will likely never need to be slowed down again.

Comment: It's not going to be at all easy, but could it be done? How does it compare to The Expanse, where they **hollowed out an entire asteroid and spun it up**

Comment: And also, it would be nice to have a full gravity, but we could run our train at only a half-gravity, or less...

Comment: And moreover, if you just wanted to replicate the smaller-and-faster-rotating ring stations, then just build them over the poles instead of the equator, a moon is still a sphere.

Comment: @SamKitsune The principle is fine, having a fast train is indeed low on the suspension of disbelieve scale compared to many other scifi concepts. My "probably not feasible" was only meant in a sense of whether or not we could build it now or soon. Regarding structural stress I can't help - I just know enough about that topic that I'm sure I don't know enough to say much about it.

Comment: @SamKitsune If you were to build a space habitat just as big, it *wouldn't* need to rotate just as fast because in your setup the rotatation *needs to cancel out part of Ganymede's gravity*. Why on Earth would you build it on Ganymede anyway, it sounds totally counter-productive?

Comment: Also, The Expanse is not the golden child of hard-scifi (I see you reference it a lot, which is fine, it's fine to have inspirational sources, but it's not a good guidebook for what is and isn't possible). Do you have any idea how much energy it takes to speed up Ceres' rotation like that? I remember reading something like several million Saturn V rockets, during a time when, canonically, such a thing wouldn't have been possible in-universe. It's a not-well-explained, not-well-thought-out plot device.

Comment: @BMF I clarified your point about building it on Ganymede in the comments of this post. If you want the brief of it, Ganymede is an example of a moon. I also said that it would be more efficient to build it on tiny moons that would otherwise be useless due to their size and composition. I.E. small, rocky moons without any useful ore, because the radius is smaller and thus the circumference to speed ratio is better.

Comment: @BMF I admit to relying on it a bit too much, but I just really like it because the writing style is brutally real and I like it. Just my opinion. It also introduced me to the idea of "If spaceship engine turns off, spaceship keeps moving at its speed, unless its engine turns on or it hits something." It's a totally obvious concept, but I never thought about it that way. Don't judge me to harshly, but that was when I was basically a kid, with a dream to write a book about space stuffs, because it was cool.

Comment: @SamKitsune Alastair Reynolds' Revelation Space series did much the same for me. I'm pretty young too. "The Greats" of sci-fi weren't part of my reading diet. I grew up on the run-off of writers inspired by them. Anyway, don't let negative nancies like me tell you what you should or shouldn't do in your universe. In my experience, some of the ideas we have when we're new and inexperienced turn out to be our best ones.

Comment: @BMF ^-^ No worries! The idea for this was born from how badass a scene would be:

Comment: Two people, hanging off the side of a train, in space, with mag-boots, playing Texas shoot-em-up and the consequence of failure being splatting into the ground at a few hundred kilometers per second. With a foggy, gloomy canyon over their heads and hard vacuum underneath. Just an idea tho~ :P